# allowing user to create answers to multiple questions in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model relationship set up like this:

```
# User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :answers
  # groups
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :group_questions, through: :groups, source: :questions
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
  # question
  has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
  has_many :questions, through: :question_participants
```

---

```
# questions created by admin
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :question_participants
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :question_participants,
                   source: :questionable, source_type: 'User'
  has_many :groups, through: :question_participants,
                    source: :questionable, source_type: 'Group'
  has_many :companies, through: :question_participants,
                       source: :questionable, source_type: 'Company'

end
```

---

```
# user answers to questions
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end
```

now my answer stores user_id, reply (their answer) and question id.
What I'd like to be able to create now is a form that allows a user to answer all the questions asked to them, and submit the answers.

I've setup my form like this on the view file (answers#new):

```
<%= form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <% current_user.all_questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>
    <p><%= question.name %>
    <%= f.text_field :reply %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

which doesn't work, and I get why - issue is i don't know how to make it work with multiple save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your problem. Here is what I suggest:

```
<%= form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <% current_user.all_questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'questions[][id]', question.id %>
    <p><%= question.name %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'questions[][reply]' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now in the controller action you can access `params[:questions]` and you'd get smth like this: `[{"id"=>"1", "reply"=>"some text 1"}, {"id"=>"2", "reply"=>"some text 2"}]`:

```
# your_controller.rb
def create_answers
  answers = params[:questions].map do |question|
    current_user.answers.create(question_id: question[:id], reply: question[:reply])
  end

  if answers.any(&:invalid?)
    flash[:error] = 'Some answers were not accepted'
    redirect_to :back
  else
    redirect_to home_path
  end
end
```

Comment: getting undefined method for questions[][reply].  Any idea as to why?

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes, where is it raised? in the view?

Comment: yeah the text field for questions[][reply]

Comment: seems to be working! any idea on how to do a redirect after they're all saved?

Comment: It depends on what are you going to do if some of them are not saved (invalid)